# S3 sdk for Golang PutBucketLifecycleConfiguration error: error setting lifecycle policies on bucket: MalformedXML

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to add an additional filter option

```
ObjectSizeGreaterThan
```

to existing code and got the following error

```
error setting lifecycle policies on bucket: MalformedXML: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema
```

The code that's generating the error is

```
_, err = svc.PutBucketLifecycleConfiguration(&s3.PutBucketLifecycleConfigurationInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucketName),
        LifecycleConfiguration: &s3.BucketLifecycleConfiguration{
            Rules: []*s3.LifecycleRule{

                &s3.LifecycleRule{
                    ID: aws.String("s3-retention-daily"),

                    Filter: &s3.LifecycleRuleFilter{
                        Tag: &s3.Tag{
                            Key:   aws.String("retention-type-daily"),
                            Value: aws.String("true"),
                        },
                        ObjectSizeGreaterThan: aws.Int64(30720),
                    },
                    Transitions: []*s3.Transition{
                        &s3.Transition{
                            Days:         aws.Int64(30),
                            StorageClass: aws.String(s3.TransitionStorageClassDeepArchive),
                        },
                    },
                    Status: aws.String(s3.ExpirationStatusEnabled),
                },
                
            },
        },
    })
```

The golang / s3 sdk version in question are 1.17.1 / 1.44.87

I've tried printing out LifeTypeConfiguration generated by the code above.

```
Bucket: "foo-us-east-1-unique123",
          LifecycleConfiguration: {
            Rules: [{
                Filter: {
                  ObjectSizeGreaterThan: 30720,
                  Tag: {
                    Key: "retention-type-daily",
                    Value: "true"
                  }
                },
                ID: "retention-daily",
                Status: "Enabled",
                Transitions: [{
                    Days: 7,
                    StorageClass: "DEEP_ARCHIVE"
                  }]
              },{
                AbortIncompleteMultipartUpload: {
                  DaysAfterInitiation: 3
                },
                Filter: {
                  Prefix: ""
                },
                ID: "incomplete_uploads",
                Status: "Enabled"
              }]
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out to use And condition uses a different operator below code works

```
&s3.LifecycleRule{
                    ID: aws.String("retention-daily"),
                    Filter: &s3.LifecycleRuleFilter{
                        And: &s3.LifecycleRuleAndOperator{
                            ObjectSizeGreaterThan: aws.Int64(30720),
                            Tags: []*s3.Tag{&s3.Tag{
                                Key:   aws.String("retention-type-daily"),
                                Value: aws.String("true"),
                            }},
                        },
                    },
                    Transitions: []*s3.Transition{
                        &s3.Transition{
                            Days:         aws.Int64(3),
                            StorageClass: aws.String(s3.TransitionStorageClassDeepArchive),
                        },
                    },
                    Status: aws.String(s3.ExpirationStatusEnabled),
                },
```